# How to fix 'Unable to annotate image' error when using ImageMagick?

Tags: php, imagick

I am using php 7.0.19 and ImageMagick 6.9.6-4 on a FreeBSD 11.0 server.  I use imagemagick for quite a few things, but I am just getting started with using it to overlay text on top of my images.  The problem I'm having is that any time I try to use the annotateImage functionality an error is thrown that simply says 'Unable to annotate image.'

I have looked through quite a few questions related to annotateImage here on stackoverflow and I have checked the docs to see if I could resolve the issue on my own, but I'm stuck. On other annotateImage questions I have seen that some people have trouble due to not having a specific font installed, and that may be my problem as well, but I have tried placing a font file (the ttf file) in the same directory as my script and I am still having the same issue.

Running `convert -list font` returns an empty result, indicating that there are no fonts that imagemagick has direct/default access to; however, I was thinking that by including the font file in the same directory as my script I could make it work anyway.  Perhaps this is a mistaken assumption?

Here is the code I am using for my test:

```php
$imagick = new Imagick('originalImage.jpg');
$draw = new ImagickDraw();
$draw->setFillColor('#ffffff');
$draw->setFont('ARIAL.TTF');
$draw->setFontSize(20);
$imagick->annotateImage($draw, 20, 100, 0, 'The quick fox jumps over the lazy dog');
$imagick->drawImage($draw);
$imagick->writeImage('finalImage.jpg');
```

I have also tried other example scripts that don't require an original image, and received the same error.  For example, this script produces the same error:

```php
$image = new Imagick();
$draw = new ImagickDraw();
$pixel = new ImagickPixel( 'gray' );
$image->newImage(800, 75, $pixel);
$draw->setFillColor('black');
$draw->setFont('ARIAL.TTF');
$draw->setFontSize( 30 );
$image->annotateImage($draw, 10, 45, 0, 
    'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog');
$image->setImageFormat('png');
header('Content-type: image/png');
echo $image;
```

With this simple test I was expecting to add 'The quick fox jumps over the lazy dog' over the top of my image, but instead an exception is thrown and the error message simply says: Unable to annotate image.

Any ideas or suggestions on how I can resolve the error?

Thanks!

Comment: Fonts are to be found in the type.xml file. But you may need to add them manually. See https://imagemagick.org/script/resources.php for locations. Otherwise, provide the full path to your font file. That should always work. Sorry, I cannot comment further about your  Imagick code, as I do not use that API.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've actually also tried using the full path to the font file, but unfortunately I receive the same error.  I wish the error provided a little more detail about what the actual problem is, but hopefully someone else has had a similar issue and can respond with what worked for them.  Thanks again!

Comment: I have answered you post on the ImageMagick forum at https://imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=36087. Your code works fine for me. Perhaps your install is bad. Are you sure your font file is OK and referenced properly and located where you think it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through posting this question on the [imagemagick forum](https://imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=36087), I was able to get it figured out. The problem was that our ImageMagick install is missing the 'freetype' delegate, which is required for rendering text from fonts.

Thanks!